# Same custom field on both Location screen and Customer screen

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to add the same custom field in Acumatica 2017 R2 to **both** the Location screen (AR303020) and the Customers (AR303000) screen. There are other native fields found on the "Customers > Delivery Settings" tab that exhibit the behavior I'm trying to match. (Example: Tax Registration ID, Tax Zone, etc.) These fields can be viewed/edited from either the Customers screen or the Locations screen.

Using the Customization Project browser I'm able to add the field to the Location screen easily enough.

[image: CR.Location definition]

Next, I would like to add a new custom field into the "Customers > Delivery Settings tab > Default Location Settings group" that uses the same DAC as the custom field that was added to the Locations screen.

But I'm not sure how to properly define the same field for the Customers screen. By default, the Customization Browser adds a custom field to the CR.Address DAC. I've tried creating a new CR.Address field with this definition:

[image: CR.Address definition]

There are no errors during publishing, but Acumatica will not load the Customer or Locations screens. The error is "Invalid column name 'UsrCertificateDate". I intentionally did not add a column for UsrCertificateDate to the CRAddress database table because the column was previously added to the Location table. I'd prefer not to maintain two database fields if only one is needed.

How can I make a custom field on these two screens work together? Editing the Default Location from the Customers screen should change the value when viewing the Location from the Locations screen and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should consider declarations of DAC Location and Address:

Location:

```
[Serializable]
public class Location : IBqlTable, IPaymentTypeDetailMaster, ILocation
{
  .
  .
```

Address:

```
[Serializable]
public class Address : IBqlTable, IAddressBase, IValidatedAddress, IPXSelectable
{   
   .
   .
   .
```

as you can see from declarations, both of them implement IBqlTable, so it means that Location and Address live as separated entities in Acumatica.
Following sql in your db will show to you that both tables have their own life:

```
select top 10 * from Location

select top 10 * from Address
```

you will see different outputs. It also means that you can't use one DAC extension for the same table, but you'll need to extensions. And also you'll need to add two columns for Location and Address table.

One more point for you to be careful, there is a difference between DAC which is CR.Address and CRAddress.

Take a look at CRAddress declaration:

```
[Serializable]
public class CRAddress : IBqlTable, IAddress, IAddressBase, IValidatedAddress
{
    .
    .
    .
```

as you can see from declaration, entity CRAddress is third table. 
If to assume all of this you'll either to add the same column twice to Location and Address DAC extensions, or as another option you can create table CertificationDates which will have Certifications dates as one of the columns, and in both extensions to have ID for CertificationDates as foreign key.